# Is the affix/root/combining-form model necessary to understand medical terminology?

Tags: grammar, terminology, morphology

I am learning medical terminology. My medical terminology textbook has me confused about roots, prefixes, suffixes, and combining forms. As a neophyte to morphology, I am trying to understand why it is critical to classify individual word parts as a prefix, suffix, root, or combining form, when trying to determine the meaning of a word. Is it that a word part can have a different meaning based on whether it occurs at the beginning of a word versus the end of a word, e.g. *an-* vesus *-an*?

What is troubling me is that my medical terminology textbook provides a cursory introduction to the concepts of root, prefix, suffix, and combining form that imply rules which are contradicted later in the textbook. For instance, the book implies that prefixes and suffixes cannot stand alone; that they must be applied to a root. This then implies that every word must contain a root. The textbook presents *poly-* as a prefix and *-graph* as a suffix. But then introduces the word *polygraph*. If *poly-* is a prefix and *-graph* is a suffix, where is the root?

I then looked to several dictionaries for help. What I found was that they often disagreed on the classification of word parts. For example, the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=poly-) classifies *poly-* as a prefix, but the [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poly-) classifies *poly-* as a combining form.

Should I worry less about classifying each word part and worry more about recognizing word parts and their meaning (keeping in mind that word part position within a word is important)? Or should my medical terminology textbook be more rigorous in choosing and applying a consistent morphological model, or at least notifying the reader of exceptions?

My goal is not only to learn medical terminology, but also to convey it to others in a clear and concise manner.

Thank you.

Comment: Words and word parts are polymorphic. Graph can be a suffix but it can also be a root word itself. Poly can be a prefix, but it can be a proper noun ("Poly"). So "polygraph" is a prefix of "poly" modifying the root "graph". There's no contradiction there, and your textbook is on solid ground.

Comment: Please add blank lines betwen paragraphs so that your wall of text is easier to read.

Comment: @tchrist - I've divided my original question into multiple paragraphs and made a slight modification to the wording of the last sentence. I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: @slax Much better, thanks.

Comment: @DMac - I implied there was a contradiction because the textbook did not teach about polymorphism; nor did it explain in a more general way that _-graph_ can be a suffix in some uses and a root in others. The textbook simply listed _-graph_ as a suffix. My conjecture is that because there is minimal text describing morphology in the textbook, I was unable to correctly classify word parts and consequently became confused. The textbook does not discuss morphology. It only introduces prefixes, suffixes, roots, and combining forms. I discovered morphology as I searched for answers.

Comment: Combinations of roots are common in medical terms. _Pneumothorax_, for example. Just like noun compounds in English (_pony ride_). The 'root' and 'stem' metaphors are mostly applied to Latin words, where each  basic root has several different forms (the present stem, the perfect stem, the participle stem), each with some differences from the root, but usually containing (a part of) the root, just like the plant metaphor suggests. The word is the adult plant, with all its parts.